# How to round output rectangles of SquarifiedTreemap algorithm so they can fit a grid with every tile being 1x1

Tags: c#, rectangles

this can be trivial but nonetheless I need help... :)

I have a grid, every tile of the grid is 1x1. The rectangles returned by the SquarifiedTreemap algorithm are in floating point. I need to round the values to integers so they can fill the grid.

I've tried to round the values of the rectangles to the nearest integer, but results are inconsistent, sometime one rectangle overlap another, some other time there's a gap between two rectangles.

Here's an example with a grid 20x10, ratios are [30, 28, 15].

```
regular: (x:0.00, y:0.00, width:8.41, height:10.00)
rounded: (0, 0, 8, 10)

regular: (x:8.41, y:0.00, width:7.25, height:10.00)
rounded: (8, 0, 7, 10)

regular: (x:15.65, y:0.00, width:4.35, height:10.00)
rounded: (16, 0, 4, 10)
```

As you can see, the total area of the grid is 200, but the total area of rounded rectangles is 190. In fact, in my grid there's a 1x10 gap between two rectangles.

Thank you.

Comment: You'd have to apply the rounding to the total volume, rather than one (or more) of the factors. This is possibly more of a math question than programming per se.

Comment: You're right, but I'm not sure how to proceed. Also, once the rectangles are rounded, the positions have to change accordingly.

Comment: In truth, I don't know. It might be worth posting on math.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: This is a good advice, thank you.